# What is needed for a G-matrix?

Tags: evolution, literature, quantitative-genetics

I have been doing a lot of reading on quantitative genetics and the [G- (and B-) matrix](http://www.bio.tamu.edu/users/ajones/gmatrixonline/whatisg.html) lately. I get the principle behind performing the analysis now but I am still not sure how to do it. I'd like to be able to try it out with some dummy/old data in R to see how it is done.

Let's pretend I have measured 5 traits of Drosophila (Wing length, lifespan, eye pigmentation, bristle number, and fitness). Could I construct a G-matrix for the population from this data and also get a B-matrix to measure the selection on the traits?

**Aims of the post:**

1) What information (trait measurements, fitness scores etc.) is needed to construct G- and B- matrices?

2) I would like to find print or online material that would guide me in actually implementing this method. It seems like there is an awful lot of papers saying that G-matrices are great, but no one actually says how to do them in real life...

Comment: Your link talk about G-matrix only. I don't know what a B-matrix is. Do you have a link that explain what is a B-matrix? Thks

Comment: @Remi.b The b-matrix is a sub matrix within the g-matrix (the g matrix is constructed of four sub matrices, Gm [male genetic variance and covariance] Gf for female too, B (and B transposed) with the cross sex genetic covariance

Comment: A short description of what is a G-matrix can be found in [this question](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21058/evolution-of-the-g-matrix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To construct the G-matrix you need additive genetic variances and covariances for all traits, so you normally need results from breeding experiments (e.g. phenotypic midparent-offspring data), that you can do parent-offspring regressions on. Don't know any good online sources but see [Balding et al. 2007](http://books.google.no/books?id=hFjNvMWBk14C&pg=PA535&lpg=PA535#v=onepage&q&f=false) p. 534ff for some info. I've seen methods that claim that the G-matrix can be estimated directly from phenotypic data from unrelated individuals (e.g. [Zintzaras 2011](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs12041-011-0021-x)) or from genomic info e.g. SNPs ([Vattikuti et al. 2013](http://www.plosgenetics.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pgen.1002637)), but are not familiar with these and do not know how reliable they are.

A clear background on using mixed models to estimate the G-matrix, including examples/tutorials, can be found in [Wilson et al (2009)](http://www.wildanimalmodels.org/tiki-download_wiki_attachment.php?attId=22).

Or did you have something else/something more specific in mind?

Comment: There is really two aspects to this for me I guess. Firstly, I'd like to know how they can be done. Secondly I am trying to figure if I could do them using trait values from hemiclonal lines of drosophila such that I get sex specific trait values for each haplotype and can therefore make a B matrix.

Comment: Well, you should be able to get genetic variances from hemiclonal lines - you need to carefully consider exactly how to calculate them and the amount of heritability captured though. What do you mean with: "*Firstly, I'd like to know how they can be done*". What the matrices contain, how to technically peform the regressions or something else? I suspected that you were after something more specific, but you should update the question to make it less unclear.

Comment: Also, have you looked at *Animal models* (statistical mixed models), where the entire pedigree can be used to estimate components of the G-matrix?

Comment: what I mean by "how they can be done" is what sort of data do I need, what needs to be measured, as it already says in the question

Comment: @GriffinEvo I guess this is what is unclear to me; in the simple case, what you need for a G-matrix is phenotypic data on the traits of interest and a known relationship between individuals (e.g. parent-offspring). I also wrote this in my answer, but apparently you are looking for something else. To account for e.g. environmental factors, sex or a known pedigree you need a more complex statistical model, e.g. *Animal models*. I have updated my answer with a paper that might be of use.